# How do I find any word that contains all the given characters at least once

Tags: java

I working with this code

```
                   while((dictionaryWord = br_.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                if(dictionaryWord.matches("^"+word.replace("*" , "." )+"$"))
                {   
                    incrementCounter();
                    System.out.println(dictionaryWord);
                }
            }
```

**Desired Goal: word = dgo**

**Output: dog, god, dogma megalogdon, etc....**

Comment: What if the input is "good". Should "dog" be in the output?

Comment: Could there be accented characters, or characters outside the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)?

Comment: @MarkByers yeah as long as each character is present at least once

Comment: @MarkByers only the 26 letters of the english alphabet

Comment: I'm sure there is a regex to do this but you can always you `indexOf` or `contains` in a loop over all the `chars` in the desired word.

Comment: Repost? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567365/how-do-i-find-words-that-only-contain-consist-of-a-given-char-sequence

Comment: @user845279 Thanks for tipping off. And he even got an accepted answer there!

Comment: @user845279 Actually the other question was slightly different.

Comment: Different questions but good observation

Comment: possible duplicate of [GREP How do I only retrieve words with only the specified letters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566812/grep-how-do-i-only-retrieve-words-with-only-the-specified-letters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a [`Set<Character>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of all the chars in `word`, and iterate it. If one character is not in `dictionaryWord`, then `dictionaryWord` does not fit. Only if all appear - print `dictionaryWord`

```
    String word = "dog";
    String  dictionaryWord;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while((dictionaryWord = br.readLine()) != null)  {
        Set<Character> chars = new HashSet<Character>();
        for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
            chars.add(c);
        }
        boolean match = true;
        for (Character c : chars) {
            String s = "" + c;
            if (!dictionaryWord.contains(s)) {
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (match == true) 
            System.out.println(dictionaryWord);
    }
```

In the above code, the set creation can be moved out of the `while` loop, of course.

More efficient solution could be to create a `Set` from `dictionaryWord` as well, and then check if the intersection of the two sets is identical to the set representing `word`.

This will be:

```
    String word = "dog";
    Set<Character> set1 = new HashSet();
    for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
        set1.add(c);
    }
    String  dictionaryWord;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while((dictionaryWord = br.readLine()) != null)  {
        Set<Character> set2 = new HashSet();
        for (char c : dictionaryWord.toCharArray()) {
            set2.add(c);
        }           Set<String> intersection = new HashSet(CollectionUtils.intersection(set1, set2));
        if (set1.equals(intersection)) {
            System.out.println(dictionaryWord);
        } else System.out.println("bad");
    }
```

using [`CollectionUtils.intersection()`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#intersection%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) from apache commons

Comment: could you produce this example. Thanks if possible

Comment: @stackoverflow: Just provided a code that reads from System.in, and matches for "dog", you can check it out.

Comment: @stackoverflow: I also added another - more efficient way to do it.

Comment: You don't need `CollectionUtils`: `set2.retainAll(set1); if(set1.equals(set2))...` will accomplish the same.

Comment: For the record, turning both strings (or char seqs) into sets cannot possibly improve the original performance, which is O(n+m). It may look in your code that there's one loop less, but think about what that call to `intersection` needs to do. The only optimization I see is making a set of `word` chars once and reusing that set since many words are checked against that same set.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I disagree for two reasons. (1) The original is `O(|set|*|dictionaryWord| + |word|)`, since each `contains()` is itself `O(n)`, and you do it `|set|` times. (2) The size of `set1` and `set2` is bounded to 26, while the size of the string is not. So, with combination of (1) - minimizing the number of times reading `dictionaryWord` is a priority, and the 2nd solution does it only once.

Comment: This is what I have in mind: leave `dictionaryWord` as it is -- you only need to iterate over all its chars once. Make the required chars a Set to prevent O(n^2), but make it a singleton set and reuse in each check of `dictionaryWord`. Now you have only O(|dictionaryWord|) (plus hash lookup overhead, whetever that is, but it's not much worse than O(1)).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: If you want it to be as fast as possible (though unreadable) - you can use a simple `int` as a bit-set (it fits since 32 bits are enough for 26 possible elements), populate it in a single iteration over `dictionaryWord`, and use `operator&` to create intersection of the two sets. Then, just simply check if  `set1 & set2 == set1`. I doubt you can get any faster then it..

Comment: No, I said it's O(|dictionaryWord|) with a note that hash lookup itself is slightly worse than O(1), which makes the total complexity slightly worse than O(|dictionaryWord|). I wouldn't limit my solution to lowercase ascii, btw.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yea, editted the comment - I misunderstood you on first read. The OP clearly asks for 26 chars, SO is about answering a specific question - and not general cases... so for this *specific* question - the `int` solution is as fast as you can get.

Comment: True, OP made that clear in the comment. `BitSet` seems like a nice approach in that case (instead of a raw `int`).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final BitSet reqChars = new BitSet(26);
  for (char c : "dog".toCharArray()) reqChars.set(Character.toLowerCase(c) - 'a');
  for (String w : new String[] {"god", "dogma", "megalogdon", "dorm"})
    if (hasAllChars(w, reqChars)) System.out.println(w);
}

public static boolean hasAllChars(String in, BitSet req) {
  req = (BitSet)req.clone();
  for (char c : in.toCharArray()) {
    req.set(Character.toLowerCase(c) - 'a', false);
    if (req.isEmpty()) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This is a bad solution because you go to the end of the word after a miss. Suppose you have a 20 character word and the second one misses. That's 5% efficiency.

Comment: @Rob You misunderstand my code. My set contains the required chars. The input word is allowed to contain chars outside the required set of chars, that's not a **miss**.

Comment: Yeah the name is misleading. hasAllChars would imply the string would contain all the characters. I did a version of that in my answer.

Comment: @Rob It reads "in *has all chars of* req" and that's what it does.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean containsAllCharacters(String word, Set<String> characters){
    int i = 0;
    int wordLength = word.getLength();
    while (i <= wordLength && characters.contains(word.get(i++)){}
    return i==wordLength;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct. What happens with the input "dogma" and character set "ogd" when you reach the 'm'?

Comment: Yeah I saw the solution from @Marko and supplied an implementation of his method. I will modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the most interesting part of this question is how to avoid looking at every word in the dictionary (though the original code kind of glosses over that). A potentially interesting answer to that would be this:

1. Make a table of the 26 characters by frequency of occurrence.
2. Lookup each of the characters, getting the least frequently occurring one.
3. Then do matches of words that contain that character.

This is assuming, of course, that a single match is cheaper than a regex.

Awesome wikipedia page on the topic [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency). In this case, the differences might not be huge but in something with e and x for instance, it would be.